# Change links hover colors via css

Tags: css, hover, joomla3.0

I have changed this on other parts of the site. But for some reason on this page nothing is working.

The link to the page in question is:
http://mb.cholentmt.com/update/index.php/games/event/739-test-tyes

I want to change the following text to black on hover:

- Dexter Park
- Basketball

I have tried the following `CSS` code in my browser debugger with nothing working:

```
ul.rstpl_event_inner_details a:hover, 
    ul.rstpl_event_inner_details a:active, 
        ul.rstpl_event_inner_details a:focus 
{
    color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule should work:

`#rs_event_show .rstpl_event_inner_details a:hover { color: black !important; }`

The rule wasn't applied because there is another **!important** rule set.

In order to override it you have to make your rule more specific. You could get more information about specificity at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: @MusicalWebsites please accept this answer if it was helpful in finding your solution...

Comment: @mostafaznv I did. At first it said I had to wait a few minutes before I could do it.